# How to force Intellij to highlight file with no extension as Bash?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm editing Linux `init.d` scripts with Intellij IDEA 12 Ultimate and would like it to use Bash syntax highlighting. I already have the Bash syntax highlighting plugin, and it works great for files ending in `.sh`. The problem with the init.d scripts is they have no extension, and it seems the only way to get Intellij to recognize a files type (Preferences -> File Types -> Registered Patterns) is by extension. If Registered Pattern supported paths (like `*/etc/rc.d/init.d/*`) that would be swell, but that doesn't seem to work.

The only workaround I've found for now is to add the name of each script I want to edit to Registered Patterns. Better than nothing, but does is there a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `*.` pattern. Though it's registered for `Text files` type by default.

Comment: Thanks, this does do exactly what I asked. Unfortunately, it then also interprets all extension-less files as Bash scripts. So it's either this or adding scripts file by file to the list.

Comment: FYI, there is an bug in the project related to this topic: https://github.com/jansorg/BashSupport/issues/262

Comment: This is not the correct solution (you don't want all extension-less files to be marked as Bash). Use BashSupport instead (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42222901/1892116)

Answer (score 10):

If you happen to have previously registered a file with IntelliJ (ex. when you initially create the file) that the file should be interpreted as Text this would add your file to the default mapping for Text in preferences. If you intend to create a file as Bourne Again Shell (aka bash) then at this point just tell IntelliJ that is what you intend. Otherwise you will need to manually go and remove these custom mappings from preferences before these files will show up for Bourne Again Shell.
[image: Preferences - Editor - File Types - Text]

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to do this:

- Install the BashSupport plugin for IntelliJ
- Right click the file you want highlighted
- Choose "Associate with filetype"
- Select "Bourne Again Shell"

All similar files will be recognized as bash.

Comment: Cleanest answer for one offs I think, confirmed in 2017.2

Answer (score 5):

To make IntelliJ recognize a file without extension [i.e. `install`] as a bash file:

1. Create a file `install.bash` - after creating IntelliJ will recognize both files, `install` & `install.bash` as bash files
2. Now  delete the `install.bash` file.
3. The file `install` remains marked as a bash file.

This worked for me (IntelliJ Idea 15), even after restarting IntelliJ all files were marked as bash files..

**Update for IntelliJ 2016:**

Adding the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env bash` makes idea recognize the files without the `.sh` extension as well

Comment: Any update to this? Facing same issue in IntelliJ 2016.1 and no luck after trying all proposed solutions.

Comment: @prometheus2305 did you try using the shebang line?

Comment: You need to make sure there are no spaces after the shebang

Comment: This should be the accepted response for recent versions of IntelliJ. Worked great for me for IntelliJ 2017.1

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE for anyone stumbling across this issue.

As of the latest version (2018.2.6), Intellij comes with an "Associate with File Type" for files without an extension. Just right-click on the file in projects and if the file has no extension this option should be available as the second option under new. Just don't click too fast as the associate option disappears once your selection is made.

Found this trying to figure out how to associate JS files without an extension.

Answer (score 3):

The BashSupport plugin *will* work, but it doesn't cope with spaces after the shebang.

`#!/usr/bin/env bash`

not

`#! /usr/bin/env bash`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else stumbling across this older question, the BashSupport plugin for IntelliJ will do this out of the box.

Comment: Not as far as I can tell. Works for .sh files but not files with no extension.

Comment: [so you heard it through the grapevine?](https://www.ansorg-it.com/en/products_bashsupport.html), HOW.