# Force Intellij to associate files without any extension as bash

Tags: intellij-idea

How do I get Intellij to treat any file without an extension as bash syntax?

I've tried several proposed solutions such as adding bash support module with no luck.

Comment: potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616041/how-to-force-intellij-to-highlight-file-with-no-extension-as-bash